# convert input text into multiple line in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a textarea where user input will be converted into 2 separate lines (li) if the length of the text is greater than 10.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [area, setArea] = useState([]);
  const [newText, setNewText] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    let val = event.target.value;
    //convert to array
    const arr = val.split("");
    setArea(arr);
  };

  const changeNewText = () => {
      setNewText(area);

  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea onChange={onChange} />
      <br />
      <br /> 
      <button onClick={changeNewText}>change text</button>
      <br />
      {newText.length < 10 ? newText : "text is too long"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

currently, it can show only text if the length of the text is less than 10, however, if it is bigger than 10, it will show 'text is too long.

How would you make it to divide the text into two lines instead?

For example, let's say the text user input

```
Hello, the earth revolves around sun.
```

should compile to

```
 - Hello, the
 - n earth re
```

both these lines should either be a div or li element.

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is. Do you want to chunk up/split the `textearea` into an array of strings no longer than 10 characters? Or do you need to use the existing conditional rendering of `"text is too long"`?

Comment: @DrewReese conditional rendering is just the placeholder, I want to split the textarea into an array of strings no longer 10 characters. If the text area is longer than 10 characters, it should split into 2 lines.

Comment: So chunk/split the string and render an array of strings into `div` or `li` elements. Have you tried this already?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chunk string

```
ArrayString = str.match(/.{1,10}/g);
```

The code should be like this

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [area, setArea] = useState([]);
  const [newText, setNewText] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (event) => {
    let val = event.target.value;
    //convert to array
    const arr = val.split("");
    setArea(arr);
  };

  const changeNewText = () => {
      setNewText(area);

  };

ArrayString = newText.match(/.{1,10}/g);

Var text = <div></div>
For (let i = 0; i < ArrayString.length; i++) {
 text.append(<li>ArrayString[i]</li>)
}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea onChange={onChange} />
      <br />
      <br /> 
      <button onClick={changeNewText}>change text</button>
      <br />
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is working.